# ActionScript - how to put 10 different dishes (loaders) in a random sequence?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, adobe

Hello im with a doubt and need your help if its possible.
I have a class dish and i load 1 file ".swf", and i have a little game that works like this:
The dish moves in the x and y axis and i when i click in the dish it falls down.
But i want to have not only 1 dish i want have 10 different dishes with diferent images.
And i want that they appear in a random sequence.
But i dont have ideia how i cant do that...someone can give me "light"?

I use this variables to load my dish to the stage in my game project.

```
var load_dish:Loader = new Loader();
var path:URLRequest = new URLRequest("dish.swf");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example of what you could do to get a random dish each time :

```
// whenever you need to create a new dish 

var dishFilenames:Array = ['dish1.swf', 'dish2.swf', 'dish3.swf']; // etc etc 
var randomIndex:int = Math.random() * dishFilenames.length;
var filename:String = dishFilenames[randomIndex];
var load_dish:Loader = new Loader();
var path:URLRequest = new URLRequest(filename);
```

Comment: I try that but dont works! I tried that code but appears always the same dish!

Comment: Should work just fine, you must not have copied something incorrectly or have some other issue in your existing code. As long as you have an array of multiple unique filenames, this should work just fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer...i adapt your code to my work but what happens is that the randomIndex result is always the same so i get always the same dish that is the dish in the first ([0]) position!

Comment: how many dishes are in your array ? If you have 10, randomIndex will not always be 0. Again, you have copied incorrectly or something of that nature. If you only have one dish in the array, then of course you will only ever get the first dish.

Comment: i have 2 dishes just to test now, i update my code can u see if everyting is alright? thanks 1 more time!

Comment: There is nothing for me to verify, the above code works. If you are unclear on how to use it, you need to take a step back and learn some fundamental programming concepts that can help you apply this answer. I am not going to debug your code for you.

Comment: Sorry if that sounded harsh, I do wish you luck. I believe this answer is rather straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

thank for the answer!
so i cant have all the dishes in the same "swf"?
I need to create swf as many as i need?
My class dish is like this until now:
I dont have other way to do that?(with only a swf that contains all the dishes)

package  {

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;




public class Dishe {

    var velX: int;
    var velY: int ;


    var game:Game; //i have also a class game to control everyting
    var broken_dish:URLRequest = new URLRequest("broken_dish.swf");
    var gravity:int = 2;

    var dishFilenames:Array = [ 'dish.swf','second_dish.swf']; 
            var randomIndex:int = Math.random() * dishFilenames.length;
            var filename:String = dishFilenames[randomIndex];
            var load_dish:Loader = new Loader();
            var path:URLRequest = new URLRequest(filename);

    public function Dishe(e:Game, vX:int, vY:int)
    {
        velX = vX;
        velY = vY;
        load_dish.x = -180;
        load_dish.y = randomBetween(250,-5);
        load_dish.load(caminho);
        game = e; 
        game.myStage.addChild(load_dishe);
        load_dish.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, _shoot);

        }

    public function broken_dish(e:Event)
    {

        velY += gravity;
        load_dish.y +=velY ;
        if(load_dish.y >= game.myStage.stageHeight)
        {
            game.game_states(Game.state_playing);
        }

    }

public function _enterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if(load_dish.content!=null)
    {
        load_dish.x += velX;
        load_dish.y += velY *(1 - (load_dish.x / game.myStage.stageWidth) * 2 );
    if(load_dish.x > game.myStage.stageWidth)
    {
         load_dish.y = randomBetween(250,-5);
         load_dish.x = -180;

    }

    }
}

    public function _shoot(e:MouseEvent):void
    {

        trace("nice!!");
        game.game_states(Game.state_stop);
        load_dishe.load(broken_dish);   
    }
    function randomBetween(a:int, b:int) : int {
        return a + int(Math.round( (b-a)*Math.random() ));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You weren't clear about what you wanted.  You can have all the dishes in the same .swf if you want. If a dish is on each frame, just change the frame to whatever dish you want with `gotoAndStop()` - You said you wanted 10 different loaders, which is why I assumed you had multiple .swf's each with a different dish.